# Updating a list in mvvm makes List inconsistent

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am getting an exception while updating a List from a different list. For eg: List
I have some employees in List 1 and want to add it to the List 2 that already has some employees. So List2 becomes List1 + List 2. **List 2 is binded to the UI.**
But I am getting exception that states that **List 2 is now inconsistent.**
I can use **ObservableCollection** instead of List but, List 2 is a part of a dll provided. I can't change it.
How shall I move further ?

Sample Code:

```
        private void AddCommandFunction(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                var lstToBeCopied= objToBeCopied  //getting this from a different method
                var myList= (Employee)obj;
                foreach (var value in objToBeCopied.Employees)
                {
                    myList.Employees.Add(value);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        } //getting exception after this point.
```

Comment: So your `Employee`-Type has a Property called  `Employees` of type `List<T>`...? Confusing..... isn't it? Could You include your Type please?

Comment: Please update your question to provide the shortest code necessary to reproduce the issue. This way we can properly review your code. Right now, there is noting to review.

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM, a ViewModel is a "translator" between the Model and the View.  The model formats it's data in whatever manner is most convenient for itself.  It seems your `Employee` object is the Model.  The view model now needs to create a structure that can be used by the view.

In this case, you could use an ObservableCollection to wrap the list.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; }
```

You will want to initialize this, most likely in the construtor...

```cs
Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(myList);
```

This will give you a collection that can notify, but it's a copy.  Modifying the collection will not update back to the model.  We have to do that manually.

Back in the view model constructor, register for the property's events:

```cs
Employees.CollectionChanged += OnEmployeesChanged;
```

Finally implement the changes:

```cs
public void OnEmployeesChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    switch(args.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            // Add to the employee list, use args.NewItems to get the changed items.
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            // Remove from the model list, use args.OldItems to get the changed items.
            break;
    }
}
```

There are a few other Change actions you might want to handle in the event as well.  It depends on how you are using it.

The Flaw:
Unfortunately, this is not a perfect implementation.  If anything attempts to modify the list in the model directly, the ObservableCollection can not be updated, unless the Model has it's own event you can observe to let you know to update.  However if you are in control of the List and can ensure nothing modifies it directly, this solution will work provided you always modify the ObservableCollection and not the original list directly.